# Why flow element via attribute is not working in SUMO route file

Tags: sumo

I'm using following flow element in my routes file:

```
<vType id="passenger" vClass="passenger" accel="2.6" decel="4.5" sigma="0.5" length="2.5" minGap="2.5" maxSpeed="12"/>

<flow id="flow0" type="passenger" from="center0down" via="bottom6down bottom6up" to="center0up" begin="0" period="3" number="30" />
```

But SUMO-GUI shows following error:

[image]

Whereas it is clearly stated [here](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Definition_of_Vehicles,_Vehicle_Types,_and_Routes#Incomplete_Routes_.28trips_and_flows.29) that via attribute is defined for incomplete trips and flows. Any suggestion, what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SUMO Wiki always refers to the current state of development while you are using SUMO 0.30.0. The functionality was implemented in [September 2017](https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/issues/3404#issuecomment-340164105), so it is in 0.32.0.

Comment: Verified from documentation available in sumo downloaded folder.